# How to reorganize a DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and I don't know how to word this question, but I need help on how to change a dataframe and reorganize it. I would like to minimize the large dataframe without having to manually input the data as shown in the img reference. I tried groupby() but it is not exactly what I am looking for because I also need to create 2 new columns based on the yes/no values in the existing PlayTennis column.
Let me know. Thanks in advance.

See image for reference:

[Img reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJJ1t.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to create a [pivot table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html).

See if this code helps you out.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Outlook": ["Rainy", "Overcast", "Sunny"], "Tennis": ["No", "Yes", "Yes"]})
df["Count"] = [1]*df.shape[0]
df
pd.pivot_table(df, index=["Outlook","Tennis"], columns=["Tennis"], aggfunc=sum)
```

The result I get looks like this in my Jupyter notebook:
[table of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc9VP.png)